# in onCreateOptionsMenu, onQueryTextChange(String newText) Return Wrong Position on Listview..setOnItemClickListener at ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, oncreateoptionsmenu

Respectable Gurus Bellow code return wrong position and data by clicking on listview filtered Item of ArrayAdapter, Any Suggestion will by highly appreciated. Listview easily and perfectly filtered but it returns Wrong position. Any Suggestion will by highly appreciated.

```
public class MyActivity extends 
 AppCompatActivity {

---------Variables------
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);        
Intent i = getIntent();
name2=i.getStringExtra("chiled");
postion = i.getIntExtra("id",0);
chiled= i.getStringExtra("name").replace(" ", "_");
//-------------------------Action Bar-------
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (mActionBar != null) {
----Action BarCode---------
}

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this,
        R.layout.listview_item,R.id.text);
//################# FireBaseStarts
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading List...");
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.show();
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference(chiled);
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
queryRef = myRef.orderByChild("order");
queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long b = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        imageUrls = new String[(int) b];
        int i = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot ddataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Object value = ddataSnapshot.getValue();
            adapter.add(((Map) value).get("name").toString());
            imageUrls[i] = ((Map) value).get("url").toString();
            i++;
        }
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w("Database Error is: ", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Failed to load post.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this,
                SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name", adapter.getItem(position));
        i.putExtra("id", position);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
     }
   //---------------Search Starts
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu 
menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
final MenuItem 
item=menu.findItem(R.id.inputSearch);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
searchView.setQueryHint("Search Naghma...");
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }
});
return true;
 }}
```

Whenever I click on filtered Item on a listview populated by an simple ArrayAdapter , It returns Wrong position and data (Returns Old/original populated Listview Position and list Item).
Please help I am googling about a weak.

Comment: Is there no one a single GURU to solve this problem for Newbies like me?

Comment: I'm not a typical GURU, but would try to help. How are you filtering this?